# Pear Error Deprecated

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, pear

Well I have been writing in the same style for awhile now and all of the sudden i am getting an error in pear config.

Error:

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in E:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 80

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in E:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 166
```

My Index Page (was the only thing i changed):

```
<?php

include("library/config.php"); 
include("library/functions/core.php");

// Defualt Heading
$heading = "";

// Load Page Model
loadModel($path0,$path1);

// Load User Language
loadLanguage($path0,$path1);

// Load Page Header
loadHeader();

// Load Page Body
loadPage($path0,$path1);

// Load Page Footer
loadFooter();
?>
```

The only thing i changed was the location of config.php and core.php, which got placed 1 folder deeper under a new folder named library.

Comment: my pear config? or my site config file?

Comment: are you using some framework and what is the php version in xampp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you are getting the error in `config .php` and  showing us `index.php` code

by reading error. there are some function which have in below format

```
function whatever (...)
{
   return &$somevalue;
}
```

to fix the problem , you should remove `&` before `$somevalue`

read [`this`](http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=12071)

Comment: Ty for the quick response. Worked like a charm.